# Load php var from other php file

Tags: php, var

i need to write this var from one php file

```
<?php
 $headText="Home";
?>
```

to another php file ("index.php")

Comment: You have several ways to go! But the first one would be to study basic PHP!

Comment: Learn about sessions

Comment: You'll need to provide additional information. Those files could be called in the same request, in different request from the same server, or they could be part of completely different websites. Please edit your question and provide actual details about what you are trying to accomplish including the context.

Comment: Adding to the above: If you include a PHP file and have defined the variable before the inclusion, the variable will also be available

Answer (score 0):

What i understand you need to load variable value from another php page then you need to do as:
page1.php:

```
<?php
$headText="Home";
?>
```

page2.php:

```
<?php
include('page1.php');
echo $headText;
?>
```

Comment: this is not good, when i use this is show all contant of 'page1.php' not only from var

Comment: Okay, then you can use array also instead of simple variable or can use Global varaible or also can use in session. There are a lot of options you may use.

If you have any concern then please elaborate your question once.